# Packaging LibGDX program to exe with Packr breaks code which opens URL stream

Tags: java, libgdx, packr

In my LibGDX program, I attempt to obtain the user's IP from https://api.ipify.org. When I run the jarfile directly it works as expected, but it breaks when I run the exe produced by Packr.

I compiled the jar with JDK 11.0.1 and tried bundling it with both JDK 11 and 12.
Because JDK 11 and 12 do not contain the jre folder which Packr looks for, I manually created it and copied bin and lib into it.
This is the config json I gave to Packr:

```
{
    "platform": "windows64",
    "jdk": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12",
    "executable": "ShengJi-win64",
    "classpath": [
        "desktop-1.0.jar"
    ],
    "removelibs": [
        "desktop-1.0.jar"
    ],
    "mainclass": "com.sage.shengji.desktop.DesktopLauncher",
    "minimizejre": "soft",
    "output": "out-windows64"
}
```

This code is run in the show() method for my Screen.

```java
           try {
               System.out.println("In beginning of try");
               String thisMachineIP =
                        new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                        new URL("https://api.ipify.org").openStream())).readLine();
               System.out.println("Retrieved this machine IP");
           } catch(IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch(Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

When I run the exe and print to a log file, it only prints "In beginning of try" and the window closes. It doesn't crash with "the program has stopped working"; the window just closes with no explanation. The log file does not contain the prints from either of the catches. Everything works as expected when I run the jarfile directly.

EDIT
I attempted to use LibGDX's HTTP methods instead:

```java
            Net.HttpRequest httpGet = new Net.HttpRequest(Net.HttpMethods.GET);
            System.out.println("After httpGet object creation");
            httpGet.setUrl("https://api.ipify.org");
            System.out.println("After set httpGet url");

            Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpGet, new Net.HttpResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void handleHttpResponse(Net.HttpResponse httpResponse) {
                    System.out.println("in handleHttpResponse()");
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println("in failed()");
                }

                @Override
                public void cancelled() {
                    System.out.println("in cancelled()");
                }
            });
            System.out.println("After Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest()");
```

Once again, the jarfile itself runs fine. The exe never prints "After Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest()", and also doesn't print any of the messages in the HttpResponseListener.

Comment: Why pack it with a different JDK than you tested with?

Comment: Why don't you use the HTTP methods provided by libGDX?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have to compile with JDK 11 because I couldn't get Packr to work with JDK 12 on osx. I thought that with Windows I might as well still bundle with a newer JDK. I just tried bundling with the same JDK I used to compile it and the problem persists.

Comment: @MrStahlfelge Tried that just now. Problem still persists. Failed at Gdx.net.sentHttpRequest(). I'll update the question.

Comment: If you still have no luck, try jpackager > https://github.com/raeleus/skin-composer/wiki/libGDX-and-JPackage

Comment: I just used jpackage, it worked very well. Thanks!